# 3D Unet gives "output size is too small" error

Tags: pytorch, u-net, 3d-convolution

I wrote simple 3D-Unet arch in pytorch to do segmentation on 3D images.

```
class UNet3D(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    super(UNet3D, self).__init__()

    # Encoder
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(in_channels, 64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv3d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride=2)
    )

    # Middle
    self.middle = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv3d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride=2)
    )

    # Decoder
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose3d(128, 64, kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose3d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose3d(64, out_channels, kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride=2)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    # Encoder
    print(x.shape)
    print(type(x))
    x1 = self.encoder(x)

    # Middle
    x2 = self.middle(x1)
    print(x2.shape)

    # Decoder
    x3 = self.decoder(x2)

    return x3
```

My images are one channel with rectangle size, so I am resizing them to 512

```
transform = transforms.Compose([ transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Resize((512, 512))])
```

my architecture summary seems good to me

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
    Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
        Conv3d-1    [-1, 64, 128, 128, 128]           1,792
          ReLU-2    [-1, 64, 128, 128, 128]               0
        Conv3d-3    [-1, 64, 128, 128, 128]         110,656
          ReLU-4    [-1, 64, 128, 128, 128]               0
     MaxPool3d-5       [-1, 64, 64, 64, 64]               0
        Conv3d-6      [-1, 128, 64, 64, 64]         221,312
          ReLU-7      [-1, 128, 64, 64, 64]               0
        Conv3d-8      [-1, 128, 64, 64, 64]         442,496
          ReLU-9      [-1, 128, 64, 64, 64]               0
    MaxPool3d-10      [-1, 128, 32, 32, 32]               0
  ConvTranspose3d-11       [-1, 64, 64, 64, 64]          65,600
         ReLU-12       [-1, 64, 64, 64, 64]               0
  ConvTranspose3d-13       [-1, 64, 64, 64, 64]         110,656
         ReLU-14       [-1, 64, 64, 64, 64]               0
  ConvTranspose3d-15     [-1, 1, 128, 128, 128]             513
================================================================
```

but I am getting following erro when I try to train the model

> Given input size: (64x1x512x512). Calculated output size:
> (64x0x256x256). Output size is too small

Any idea how to fix it and what is going on

PS. the error comes from maxpooling3d layer from encoder part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using 3D convolution/pooling if you input a 2D image ?

The expected input size should be **BxCxDxHxW** for a 3D convolution, not  **BxCxHxW** . In your case, **C=1** because you said you only have one channel. **B** is the batch dimension, which is usually added by the dataloader. And I suppose that you have **H=W=512**. But you have no 3rd coordinate (the depth **D** of the image, which should be a cube if you work in 3D imagery).

The 3D pooling is trying to do pooling on the channel dimension, which has value 1 since you only have one channel. Hence it returns an error because you cannot downscale more than one pixel...

You can use the Upsample function that is compatible with 3D images, instead of Resize :
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html

If you use 2D images then you need to use 2D convolutions.

Comment: I realized that my dataloader was skipping the depth, so I fixed it and it is running fine now. Though I have trouble with loss function. my dice score is coming out to be negative, but I will post the another question for that.